# What is the training complexity of Sklearn GridSearch?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

```
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(probability=False, class_weight='balanced', max_iter=100, random_state=2018, tol=1e-10),
                          param_grid={'C': [2, 5, 10] , 'kernel': 'linear'},
                          n_jobs=1,
                          refit=False,
                          cv=2,
                          scoring='f1_weighted',
                          verbose=1)
gs_clf.fit(X, y)
```

This is how I used Gridsearch with SVC to fit data. Basically, I tune number of rows of data points and number of labels against random training data and record the time consumption. Theoretically, it seems `SVC` (not `linearSVC`) with `linear` kernel uses OVO multiclass implementation and the computation complexity is O(#samples * #class * iter).

Here are my two questions I came across:

1. It seems Gridsearch is doing some internal optimization for multi-class classification. The training time goes up linear as to `log(#label)` (roughly). As opposed to single SVC training, time goes up linear as to `#label`. What is Gridsearch doing exactly under the hood?

[image: Training Complexity against numbers of labels (Rows are fixed)]

2. Training time is linearly growing as a function of max_iter when number of labels is low, e.g. `#label=2`. But it's not the case when `#label` is large. When `#label=40`, `time(max_iter=200)` is not so different from `time(max_iter=400)`. This is not only happening in gridsearch, but for SVC as well. I set the `tol` to be really small hoping that the fit always hit max iterations but it seems it does not work. What's the mechanism behind this?

I'm using sklearn 0.18.1.

Comment: 1. [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html)
2. As per my understanding of your question, you are searching for [stochastic gradient descent/SGD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html)

Comment: Where are seeing that `kernel=linear` uses `ovo`? [The docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) suggest that the default is `ovr`. For the second question, could be that adding more classes makes the classification problem easier, so the algorithm isn't get close to the `max_iter`.

Comment: @ncfirth In that doc, it says `The multiclass support is handled according to a one-vs-one scheme.`. `SVC`, is implemented in terms of libsvm rather than liblinear. So it's always `OVO` but the decision function is aggregated to `OVR`, which generates `n` scores instead of `n(n-1)/2` scores.
For the second question, I set the `tol` to be really small hoping that the fit always hits max iterations. But I don't know why that don't work